# Passbolt Installation fails: usermod www-data is currently used by process 875

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, mariadb, failed-installation

I followed the installation tutorial and ran these commands:

```
    wget -O passbolt-ce-installer-ubuntu-18.04.tar.gz https://www.passbolt.com/ce/download/installers/ubuntu/latest
    wget -O passbolt-installer-checksum https://www.passbolt.com/ce/download/installers/ubuntu/latest-checksum
    sha512sum -c passbolt-installer-checksum
    tar -xzf passbolt-ce-installer-ubuntu-18.04.tar.gz
    sudo ./passbolt_ce_ubuntu_installer.sh
```

1. Setup MariaDB
2. Configured Passbolt to be installed with Havege
3. Set the hostname
4. Set SSL to be configured in ‘auto’ with LetsEncrypt

After entering my email for Let’s Encrypt, I get the error:

`usermod: user www-data is currently used by process 875`

I’m not sure if this might be helpful but the first time I tried installing.
 After running it again, I faced this issue.

I tried to solve the problem:

1. Killed the process 
    the process just restarts itself
2. Reboot 
    same as above. the process just restarts itself and I find myself with the
   same issue
3. Tried installing without Havege
   Still ends with the same error Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I had to stop the Apache 2 service to fix this issue.

```
systemctl stop apache2
```

After that the installation process was working.

Edit: Found the solution [here](https://community.passbolt.com/t/installation-fails-usermod-www-data-is-currently-used-by-process-875/2732).